# How to fix params require for form_for contact in multi controller view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem in my contact form_for,
I have one contact form and I want to render my contact form in my product view.
If I make that I have a problem with my require params

My contact_params work in my ContactController:

```
def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :body)
end
```

I have add in my ApplicationController

```
def set_contact
   @contact = Contact.new params[:contact] || {}
end
```

and that in my ProductsControler

```
show
   @contact = :set_contact
end
```

my route are:

```
get 'contact', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'
post 'contact', to: 'contacts#create', as: 'create_contact'
```

my render is same that:

```
<%= render :partial => "contacts/contact" %>
```

and my view in _contact.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for @contact, url: create_contact_url do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name  %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_area :body  %>
 <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
```

Rails say me:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: contact):
```

If I delete require(:contact) that not work rails say me:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :contact
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is `def contact_params`? `params` is normally used in a *controller* not a *view*. For something like a contact form, also probably a `POST` action rather than `GET` as probably used to view the page.

Comment: I have edit my answer! I have make an error in my description! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in method #show of ProductsControler `@contact = :set_contact`, you should call method `set_contact` without `:`

Right code: `@contact = set_contact`

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge Params with product params
params[:product].merge!(:contact)

e.g
def company_params
    params[:company].merge!(users_attributes: {'0': user_params.to_h })
    params.require(:company).permit(
      :name, :contact_person_name, :email,
      :contact_person_number, :terms_and_conditions )
  end

Hear users_attributes is from my other form.
Works for me.

Good luck.